# Удалить все строки в конце которых нет цифр

Tags: delphi

Подскажите как реализовать. Нужно из строк все в которых в конце нет цифры:

```
Primer123
Primer4454
Primer2
1Primer
2Primer
3Primer
```

На выходе результат:

```
Primer123
Primer4454
Primer2
```

Может можно как то через Pos или PosEx сделать. Или хотя бы натолкните на мысль в какую сторону смотреть, где почитать ?

Comment: Регулярные выражения пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function EndsWithDigit(s: string): boolean;
begin
  result := Pos(s[Length(s)], '0123456789') > 0;
end;

if EndsWithDigit(S) then 
begin
  ... 
end;
```

Comment: Использую функцию вот так EndsWithDigit (S);  Но просто копируется файл и ничего не происходит. В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: @Татьяна `if EndsWithDigit(S) then begin ... end;`

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало, это я не внимательная.

Comment: @Татьяна Пожалуйста. Успехов.